# Average of a numpy array after applying a function one column at a time

Tags: python, numpy

Given:

- m models, each with a `predict` function that takes a numpy array of shape [n_samples, n_features] and returns an array of shape [n_samples], which contains 1 if the model said `yes` and 0 otherwise.
- X data points of shape [n_samples, n_features]

Expected output: for each data point how many models emitted yes.

```
out = np.zeros((n, m))
for i, m in enumerate(m_models):
    out[:, i] = m.predict(X)    # Doesn't seem to work
scores = np.mean(out, axis=1)
```

Comment: You trying assign array of shape `n` to the column with shape `m`.

Comment: what's the question or problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You trying assign array of shape `n` to the column with shape `m`. Change your `out` declaration on:

```
out = np.zeros((m, n))
```

Or assign predictions to the row:

```
for i, m in enumerate(m_models):
    out[i, :] = m.predict(X)
```